# Angular tutorial: Cannot find module './mock-heroes'

Tags: angular

I am following the steps in the https://angular.io/tutorial, at this point I am stucked in step 5 (service). I get the following error:

> C:/wamp/www/Angular/primerProyectoAngular/src/app/hero.service.ts
>   (4,24                                            ): Cannot find module
>   './mock-heroes'.

This is the hero.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
 getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
  return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
 }
```

}

Comment: In which folder did you place `mock-heroes.ts`?

Comment: Thanks for answering. In the app folder.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that the name of the file was: heores and no "heroes".

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be because you have left empty the mock-heroes.ts file. Since it could not find any export in there, the compiler will complain that 'cannot find module'.